# Creating a Phoenix table view with existing Hbase tables of common names

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix

I've cloned a table and I'm trying to create a Phoenix view for it according to https://phoenix.apache.org/faq.html#How_I_map_Phoenix_table_to_an_existing_HBase_table.

Suppose I have two HBase tables below.

```
hbase(main):008:0> describe 'USERINFO'
Table USERINFO is ENABLED                                                                                                                                                                                                           
USERINFO, {TABLE_ATTRIBUTES => {coprocessor$1 => '|org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.ScanRegionObserver|805306366|', coprocessor$2 => '|org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.UngroupedAggregateRegionObserver|805306366|', coprocessor$3 => '
|org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.GroupedAggregateRegionObserver|805306366|', coprocessor$4 => '|org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.ServerCachingEndpointImpl|805306366|', coprocessor$5 => '|org.apache.phoenix.hbase.index.Indexer|80530
6366|index.builder=org.apache.phoenix.index.PhoenixIndexBuilder,org.apache.hadoop.hbase.index.codec.class=org.apache.phoenix.index.PhoenixIndexCodec', coprocessor$6 => '|org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.LocalIndexSplitter|80
5306366|'}                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
COLUMN FAMILIES DESCRIPTION                                                                                                                                                                                                         
{NAME => '0', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'FAST_DIFF', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', VERSIONS => '1', COMPRESSION => 'SNAPPY', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', TTL => 'FOREVER', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', BLOCKSIZE => '6553
6', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}

hbase(main):006:0> describe 'USERPREFERENCE'
Table USERPREFERENCE is ENABLED                                                                                                                                                                                                     
USERPREFERENCE, {TABLE_ATTRIBUTES => {coprocessor$1 => '|org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.ScanRegionObserver|805306366|', coprocessor$2 => '|org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.UngroupedAggregateRegionObserver|805306366|', coprocessor$
3 => '|org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.GroupedAggregateRegionObserver|805306366|', coprocessor$4 => '|org.apache.phoenix.coprocessor.ServerCachingEndpointImpl|805306366|', coprocessor$5 => '|org.apache.phoenix.hbase.index.Indexer
|805306366|index.builder=org.apache.phoenix.index.PhoenixIndexBuilder,org.apache.hadoop.hbase.index.codec.class=org.apache.phoenix.index.PhoenixIndexCodec', coprocessor$6 => '|org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.LocalIndexSplit
ter|805306366|'}                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
COLUMN FAMILIES DESCRIPTION                                                                                                                                                                                                         
{NAME => '0', DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'FAST_DIFF', BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW', REPLICATION_SCOPE => '0', COMPRESSION => 'SNAPPY', VERSIONS => '1', TTL => 'FOREVER', MIN_VERSIONS => '0', KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'FALSE', BLOCKSIZE => '6553
6', IN_MEMORY => 'false', BLOCKCACHE => 'true'}
```

I would run the follow command to create a table view in Phoenix?

```
CREATE VIEW USERINFO ( pk VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY, "0".team VARCHAR, "0".firstname, "0".lastname )
```

```
CREATE VIEW USERPREFERENCE ( pk VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY, "0".firstname VARCHAR, "0".lastname )
```

This seems incorrect. How do I create a table view according to this situation?

Answer (score 0):

So I believe what you are missing is that you need to specify what kind of a variable each column would be. So, technically you need to mention the type of column your variable firstname will be and so on.

I tried and tested this code. First I fired up my hbase-shell(Don't worry about the DCDR, its just my namespace, our DBA's have this pretty much locked down):

```
create 'DCDR:USERINFOV2', {NAME => '0', VERSIONS => 5}

create 'DCDR:USERPREFERENCEV2', {NAME => '0', VERSIONS => 5}
```

Then I fire up my phoenix shell:

```
CREATE VIEW "DCDR:USERINFOV2" ( pk VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY, "0".team VARCHAR, "0".firstname VARCHAR, "0".lastname VARCHAR);

CREATE VIEW "DCDR:USERPREFERENCEV2" ( pk VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY, "0".firstname VARCHAR, "0".lastname VARCHAR);
```

This gives me the views. Hopefully this works for you. Let me know if not.